# String comparison with - prefix

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have list of string which is basically negative or positive integer reading from some instrument e.g. `-12.4SEC, -13.5SEC, 14.12SEC` etc. I want to sort and when I am using `compareTo()` method of string class then it is sorting lexicographically. But I want it sorted according to integer.
My output should be `-13.5SEC, -12.4SEC, 14.12SEC etc.`

But output I am getting is `-12.4SEC, -13.5SEC, 14.12SEC` etc

Comment: You need to remove the `"SEC"` and then parse to decimal. Then they will sort correctly, give it a go

Comment: Write Your own comparator for that. Extract the number part and compare it.

Answer (score 3):

If the postfixes (the `SEC` thingy) are the same everywhere, you best option is to just convert the list to doubles, and sort that. If you are using java 8, you might make it look pretty elegant:

```
input
   .stream
   .map(s -> Double.valueOf(s.replaceAll("SEC$", "")))
   .collect(Collectors.toList)
   .sort
```

In java 7 you'd have to do it imperatively, but the idea is the same: create a new list, and add the elements to it, stripping the postfix, and parsing into a `Double` as you go, then sorting the doubles.

If the postfixes have to be preserved, it makes things a bit more complicated. One possibility is create an intermediate object that has both the original string, and the parsed double, and use that for sorting:

```
private static class Wrapper implements Comparable<Wrapper> {
    String original;
    double parsed;
    public Wrapper(String original) {
        parsed = Double.parseDouble(original.replaceAll("\\D+$", ""));
        this.original = original;
    }
    public int compareTo(Wrapper other) {
        if (this.parsed == other.parsed) return 0;
        else return this.parsed < other.parsed ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Now, similarly to above:

```
input
    .stream
    .map(s -> Wrapper(s))
    .sorted
    .map(w -> w.original)
    .collect(Collectors.toList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that ignores the `"SEC"` part and treats the rest of it as a `Double`:

```
public class SECComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private static String removeSEC(String s) {
        return s.replace("SEC", "");
    }

    @Override    
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        Double d1 = Double.valueOf(removeSEC(s1));
        Double d2 = Double.valueOf(removeSEC(s2));
        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dima are you serious?!

Comment: This is no more "premature optimization" than avoiding using bubble sort or not attempting to read large files from disk byte by byte without a buffer. There is nothing "premature" about avoiding bad algorithms.

Answer (score -2):

You can write a custom comparator which sorts the strings based on the first encountered double value in the string (this is the comparator as suggested by @musefan)

```
public class DoubleComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    private double parseDouble(String string) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?[0-9]+?(.[0-9]*)");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);

        if (m.find())
            return Double.parseDouble(m.group());
        else
            throw new IllegalStateException();
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        double d1 = parseDouble(o1);
        double d2 = parseDouble(o2);

        if (d1 < d2)
            return -1;
        else if (d1 > d2)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
String[] strings = new String[] { "-12.4SEC", "-13.5SEC", "14.12SEC", "-100SEC" };

Arrays.sort(strings, new DoubleComparator());

for (String string : strings)
    System.out.println(string);
```

Output:

```
-100SEC
-13.5SEC
-12.4SEC
14.12SEC
```